# Move UIButtons back when I click on image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to move UIButtons inside the view when I tap on image, and need to move UIButtons out of the screen when I tap on same image again.

When I tap on a UIImage, 4 UIButtons move inside screen with following code without a problem.

```
    func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
        {UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
            self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedRightArrow.center = CGPoint(x: 285, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedForward.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedCross.center = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            print("Objects moved!")   
    })
}
```

But, I couldn't find a way how can I move UIButtons back to original locations when I click on same image again.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: It appears you always move the buttons (images?) into the image.  You need to check if the trashcan, arrows, etc are inside the image and move them out if they are.  Put a conditional block of code that will move the images back out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this seems really old-school, w/o any autolayout and I randomly guessed you don't change the center's elsewhere and all center's at once:

```
func imageTapped(img: AnyObject) {
   if (self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center == CGPoint(x: 30, y: 530)) {
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
            self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: -530)
            self.imageReceivedRightArrow.center = CGPoint(x: -285, y: -530)
            self.imageReceivedForward.center = CGPoint(x: -160, y: -530)
            self.imageReceivedCross.center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: -30)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            print("Objects moved!")   
    })
} else {
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
            self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedRightArrow.center = CGPoint(x: 285, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedForward.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 530)
            self.imageReceivedCross.center = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30)
        },
        completion: { finished in
            print("Objects moved!")   
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, to answer your question :

You can save the initial position for each button then on the second tap you call `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` and set the position to `self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center = initialPosition`

You also can try with translation methods from `CoreGraphics`.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
                 self.imageReceivedTrashCan.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(300, 0)
                 ....
},
        completion: { finished in
            print("Objects moved!")   
    })
}
```

Then on the second tap get back to the Identity transform

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: [.CurveEaseInOut, .AllowUserInteraction],
        animations: {
                 self.imageReceivedTrashCan.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                 ....
},
        completion: { finished in
            print("Objects moved!")   
    })
}
```

- But this method is hard coded, you should use autoLayout to make this kind of animations. [Look at here](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/autolayout-animations/)

Hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Select imageView, goto attribute inspector and **Check user interaction enabled**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *TapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveMyView:)];
[imageview addGestureRecognizer: TapRecognizer];

- (void) moveMyView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
         self.imageReceivedTrashCan.center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: -530)
        self.imageReceivedRightArrow.center = CGPoint(x: -285, y: -530)
        self.imageReceivedForward.center = CGPoint(x: -160, y: -530)
        self.imageReceivedCross.center = CGPoint(x: -30, y: -30)
    } completion:^ (BOOL completed) {}];
}]; 

}
```